# Annotation error in my android studio code

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, annotations, android-developer-api

```
import androidx.annotation.AttrRes;  
import androidx.annotation.ColorInt;
import androidx.annotation.IntRange;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.UnsupportedAppUsage;
```

So these are the lines of the code that are giving me errors.
AttrRes,ColorInt etc. are shown as marked red.
I tried some methods to solve this by checking my SDK, and by using this particular implementation in dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'
```

but still nothing is working out. I'm a student who is still learning android , it would be helpful if someone helps me to fix this.

I tried some methods to solve this by checking my SDK, and by using this particular implementation in dependencies:
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'

but still nothing is working out. I'm a student who is still learning android , it would be helpful if someone helps me to fix this.